# Как положить Map в выпадающий список с помощью Freemarker?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, map, freemarker

У меня есть класс, в котором:

```
private String action;
private Map<String, String> actions;

public Person(){
    actions = new HashMap<>();
    actions.put("plus", "plus");
    actions.put("minus", "minus");
    actions.put("multiplication", "multiplication");
    actions.put("division", "division");
}

public Map<String, String> getActions() {
    return actions;
}
public void setActions(Map<String, String> actions) {
    this.actions = actions;
}
public String getAction() {
    return action;
}
public void setAction(String action) {
    this.action = action;
}
```

и хочу получить на страничке в виде выпадающего списка:

```
<p><select name="action">
            <#list person.actions as action, value>
                ${action}=${value}
            </#list>
</select></p>
```

получаю пустой список.

пробую:

```
<#list person.actions as action>
                <${action}=${person.getActions()}
            </#list>
```

получаю:

```
freemarker.core.NonSequenceOrCollectionException: The value you try to list is an extended_hash (wrapper: f.t.SimpleHash), thus you must specify two loop variables after the "as"; one for the key, and another for the value, like <#... as k, v>)
```

Comment: написал ответ - если что не так - пишите комментарии. Я на глаз сразу в текстовое поле без проверки писал. Но вроде все должно быть ок

Comment: только вместо  ${action}=${value} надо было value="${action}">${value} , а так все правильно было

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<p>
        <select name="action">
            <#list person.actions as action,value>
                <option value="${action}">${value}</option>

            </#list>
        </select>
    </p>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! Ваш ответ решил мою проблему!

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете привести `Map` к допустимому виду.

У `Map` есть метод, который возвращает набор вхождений

```java
Set<Map.Entry<K, V>> entrySet();
```

`Set` в свою очередь уже можно итерировать.

А из вхождения (`Entry`) уже можно вытащить ключ и значение с помощью методов `Entry::getKey()` и `Entry::getValue()` соответственно.

В итоге я думаю должно получиться как-то так

```
<p>
    <select name="action">
        <#list person.actions.entrySet() as entry>
            <option value="${entry.key}">${entry.value}</option>
        </#list>
    </select>
</p>
```